# A hyperplane separates a euclidean space into two half spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

In this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane#Technical_description)
It is written the following:

> A hyperplane in a Euclidean space separates that space into two half spaces.

Is this precise? I mean a hyperplane in
$\mathbb C^n$ does not separate $\mathbb C^n$ into two half spaces. Indeed, the complement of a hyperplane in $\mathbb C^n$ is connected, it is even path connected.

Comment: It is precise given the that the space is Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Wikipedia also defines "Euclidean space" as $\Bbb{R}^n$, not $\Bbb{C}^n$, so their statement is internally consistent with their definition even if another source (who?) uses a different definition of "Euclidean space". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space

Comment: In that article the definition says "A Euclidean vector space is a finite-dimensional inner product space over the real numbers." So $\mathbb C^n$ is an Euclidien space.

Comment: @palio $\mathbb C^n$ is not an inner product space over $\mathbb R$, unless you give it an unusual inner product.

Comment: I think that saying that $\mathbb C^n$ is not an inner product space over $\mathbb R$ because the corresponding inner products are unusual is not a precise statement. Indeed, taking the real part of a hermitian product gives $\mathbb C^n$ the structure of  an inner product  space over $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a notational issue in a sense. What people usually mean by Euclidean space is something of the form $\mathbb{R}^n$. While it is true that $\mathbb{C}^n$ viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, we never call $n$-dimensional complex space a Euclidean space. The property you mentioned holds true for real $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: What do you mean by "isomorphic"? A vector space isomorphism requires that both vector spaces have the same field of scalars. The field of scalars for the vector space $\mathbb C^n$, as it is usually defined, is $\mathbb C$. So we need to make a more careful statement than just "$\mathbb C^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2n}$". Perhaps: "$\mathbb C^n$, when viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb R$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2n}$."

Comment: Yes that's correct, I edited my post to reflect that. Good catch. Thanks!